# Ace.js editor.getValue() output has extra whitespace

Tags: javascript, arduino, electron, ace-editor, code-editor

I'm trying to build a code editor using Ace.js and Electron.js. So far I have setup the editor and can write code in it. The problem arises when I try to save the code to a file. I have the following code in my app.js file:

```
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai")
editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/arduino")

editor.setOptions({
    fontFamily: "Fira Code",
    fontSize: "10pt",
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
    showPrintMargin: false,
    UseWrapMode: true,
    UseSoftTabs: true,
})

beautify.beautify(editor.session)

code = editor.getValue()

save_file.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.eapi.saveFile('text.ino', code)
})
```

and in my index.js file, I have:

```
fs.writeFile(fname, code, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      else {
        console.log('Save succesful')
      }
    })
```

The output is

[image]

and this is what it looks like in the editor:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try adding `console.log(code)` before calling `eapi.saveFile` most likely the issue is caused  by something other than the editor itself, because the code looks correct in the editor.

Comment: Hey thx for the help. I figured it out already (see my answer below). The problem was that the code variable was being set before the button click. This meant that it was getting the default code embedded in the HTML file. Now I added it after the button click and it is working properly. Anyway thx.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured it out. The problem was that the `code` variable which contains the code in the editor was being set before the button click. So this was getting the default code set in the HTML file. It's a silly mistake from my part. Here is the edited app.js file

```
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai")
editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/arduino")

editor.setOptions({
    fontFamily: "Fira Code",
    fontSize: "10pt",
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
    showPrintMargin: false,
    UseWrapMode: true,
    UseSoftTabs: true,
})

beautify.beautify(editor.session)

// Removed from here

save_file.addEventListener('click', () => {
    code = editor.getValue() // and put here
    window.eapi.saveFile('text.ino', code)
})
```